# Flutter Web: Open php script in background

Tags: php, flutter, web, post, get

so i have a php file on my server which i need to access from my flutter web code. when doing it manually in a browser or via urlLauncher in flutter it works fine.

but i need to do it in the background without opening a new tab or redirect to it.

how can i do that?

i tried http.post and http.get but nothing happens...

```
final response = await http.post(
     
      Uri.parse(phpurl),
    );
```

i also tried adding different headers but nothing helped.

Comment: You can use Dio interface that's good compare with http, please double check method accept to run this file or route before request, and have good day!

Comment: https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/networking/fetch-data would help you, I assume. If you need more assistance after that, please show what response you expected to get from your HTTP request to the PHP script, and what you actually got instead. And mention if there are any other clues to potential issues such as error message either on the PHP or flutter side that we ought to pay attention to. At the moment your question is pretty vague and as such we can only really give generic advice. See also [ask]. You can [edit] your post. Thanks.

Comment: well i just want to launch my URL from flutter code... when i type that url in any browser or do http.post via postman it works like a charm. it also works when using urlLauncher but then it opens up the link, and that is what i DON'T want. i just want to launch that url without the user recognizing.

Comment: When you say "launch", what _exactly_ do you mean? Are you saying you want the code to open the user's web browser and navigate to that URL? Or you want to display the webpage embedded inside your flutter app? Or something else?

Comment: If you are wanting your application to silently send a request to that URL in the background, without the user noticing, then please refer to the link I already provided for instructions - it shows you how to sent a GET or POST (or any other) HTTP request using flutter/dart code, and how to monitor the response which comes back.

Comment: ok just wanted to debug it and check the response but it's WORKING from localhost/debugging... but when i compile it and run it on the server it doesn't do anything! (EMPTY response)

Comment: So you gotta debug that then. What's the HTTP response code from the request? Is there any exception in flutter? Is there any error logged in the PHP error log (assuming PHP error logging is enabled - if it isn't, it should be). We can't tell what's going wrong from here, you'll need to investigate more closely.

Comment: how can i debug compiled code?! i tried writing the response to some text element but it's just plain empty. (PHP is fine because it works from localhost, web browsers, postman...)

Comment: You insert some extra code to add more logging, to examine relevant values etc. And if an error occurs hopefully your system is set up to log it already - if not, please enable that

Comment: you won't believe what the problem was: my ad-blocker blocked the post! after disabling adblock it works just fine!!!